# Need Help Understanding a Warning from Google Colab: 'Disallowed Code Execution and while Using Stable Diffusion'

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, warnings, stable-diffusion

I got this warning from Google Colab

**Warning**

You may be executing **code that is disallowed which may terminate your runtime without warning**. Colab prioritizes interactive notebook compute and disallows some types of usage when executing code without compute units as outlined in the .
Your compute unit balance is 0.

while Running Stable Diffusion
ERROR : Runtime Disconnected Due to Inactivity Issue in Google Colab & No interface is Running right now .

"Seeking Help with Google Colab Warning and Runtime Disconnection Issues: Could Someone Provide Solutions?"

"Exploring Alternatives for Running Stable Diffusion: Are There Other Interfaces Available?"

[while Running Stable Diffusion i got this warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAEDQ.png)

Google Colab Code Link :-
[Stable_Diffusion_Code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iNIL80CpnLFp_-ye0YPl586ZjBTvUo38?usp=sharing)

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)